# Split characters from string

Tags: php

I have a string which contain contact numbers. For example,

```
$contactnumber='923216210221'
```

Now I want to separate starting 5 digits e.g. '92321' in a different variable and other digit e.g. '6210221' in a different variable.

Comment: refer this to get more insigits http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [substr <sup>PHP</sup>](http://php.net/substr):

```
$partOne = substr($contactnumber, 0, 5);
$partTwo = substr($contactnumber, 6);
```

Comment: its giving me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$partOne'

Comment: You missed the ; after your initial statement:
    $contactnumber='923216210221';

Comment: You're welcome. Please flag my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$partTwo = substr($contactnumber,5);
```